# css background-image - dont change 1st image size

Tags: css

I need to make 2 images the same dimensions, so I don't want to change the size of the 1st image.

I have this thus far

```
background-image: url("1.png"), url("2.jpg");
background-position: 3% 10%, 83% 27%;
background-size:[I dont want this to have values basically], 83% 27%;   
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
position: relative;
```

I have also tried leaving the 1st value blank for bg-size but never worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

`background-size:auto, 83% 27%;`

[**From MDN:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

> The auto keyword that scales the background image in the corresponding
>   direction such that its intrinsic proportion is maintained.
>
> If the background-size is auto or auto auto: If the image has both
>   intrinsic dimensions, it is rendered at that size.  If it has no
>   intrinsic dimensions and no intrinsic proportion, it is rendered at
>   the size of the background positioning area.  If it has no dimensions
>   but has a proportion, it's rendered as if contain had been specified
>   instead.  If the image has one intrinsic dimension and a proportion,
>   it's rendered at the size determined by that one dimension and the
>   proportion.  If the image has one intrinsic dimension but no
>   proportion, it's rendered using the intrinsic dimension and the
>   corresponding dimension of the background positioning area.

Comment: Of course, knew it would be simple. Thanks. Will post as answer as of when SO lets me.